# Is there a way to make a facebook tab visible only to admin?

Tags: facebook, tabs, admin

I am publishing a page tab app to my fanpage as an admin. It is a contest and is time sensitive.

Is there a way to hide a tab from the public and be available to the page admin and unhide it when needed?

I need the url to the tab page so I can schedule my promotional social media efforts ahead of time ( in hooosuuite). I am trying to hide the tab without removing it and unhide it when I need to make the contest live.

Thank you for any input.

-Ann K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in the app settings: Sandbox Mode. Select enable and only admins/testers/developers specified in roles will be able to access it.

Comment: Now i just need a group of unbiased knowledgeable testers. :)

Comment: Thanx, this helped me making the facebook page tab for the new timeline visible again.